# Windows built-in VPN server connection fails after authentication succeeds

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, vpn

So I have a working Windows Remote Desktop connection from my laptop to my desktop but I'm trying to replace that with a VPN to conserve bandwidth on an extremely slow hotel WiFi.

So I set up the built-in VPN server on my Windows 7 desktop (following these instructions:  https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/).

I configured my router to forward ports 47 and 1723 for both TCP/UDP.  Then on my laptop I try to connect to this VPN using PPTP, and oddly it can reach the server but only to do authentication. If I put in the wrong password it will prompt me again.  But if I put in the right password, then the connection fails with the error message

> A connection to the remote computer could not be established.  You might need to change the network settings for this connection.

Things I have already tried:

1. Every possible protocol the client can connect with.
2. Changing my router's IP to something non-standard to avoid collisions.
3. Completely disabling Windows Firewall and simultaneously putting my desktop in my router's DMZ for a few seconds to see if port forwarding was the issue.
4. Checking the miniports in the Device Manager. None of them show a yellow exclamation point or error message, but for some reason I am unable to auto-update the PPTP miniport driver (error message *"The system cannot find the file specified"*).

If all else fails, something that might help would be RDP software that does a **lot** more lossy compression and uses 1/10 of the bandwidth of the built-in Windows Remote Desktop.  Commercial VPN services will not work for me because I need to connect to certain things from my home IP.

Comment: Not an expert on this subject, but check that in your router you have not given a very narrow range of LAN IPs for DHCP. Also in your TCP/IP properties of the Incoming VPN connection on Windows 7, try to assign the IP Address which is from within the Range specified in Router setup rather than leaving it as DHCP which is default for VPN connection.

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed it.  Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections ->  Incoming connections -> Properties -> IPv4 -> Properties ->  Specify IP address ->  From 192.168.0.20 to 192.168.0.30  (instead of automatic IP)